# Using assigned ranges as data source in chart VBA

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I am trying to build out a few charts off of a table of data where the numbers used as values are not next to the headers. Essentially it is a breakout of different sections with the total and I am trying to just plot the total. When recording the macro to make the chart I want, this is what it comes up with:

```
Sub Macro()
'
' Macro Macro
'

'
    Range("E44:G44,E58:G58").Select
    Range("E58").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(216, xlBarClustered).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range( _
        "$E$44:$G$44,$E$58:$G$58" _
        )
End Sub
```

I am trying to make this program work for different files which will have different amounts of rows between the headers and the total, so I have written a line to define in which row the total is, and have tried to replace the range that Excel gave when recording the macro to be:

```
    Set myrange = ActiveSheet.Range("a:a")
    If Not (myrange.Find("Total", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)) Is Nothing Then
        myrange.Find("Total", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart).Select
        totalrow = ActiveCell.Row
    End If

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(216, xlBarClustered).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("E44:G44", "E" & totalrow & ":G" & totalrow)
```

Except this ends up selecting the entire series of data between row 44 and the total row, as well as throwing off the axes and labels.

I'm not really sure how to proceed here so hoping to get some input.

Comment: The best approach to is to create a calculation sheet where you have the data organized, and then you build the charts from there.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.